# WiFi Slow Download speed, fast upload. Affects only one device

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wireless-router, broadcom

I am having a speed issue with my wireless connection - only on my laptop. All other devices are fine.

**Network configuration**
CISCO DPC3825 Cable Modem in bridge mode
ASUS N56U Dual Band Router. Firmware Version:3.0.0.4.374_239 (checked that this is the latest available)
Multiple devices connected to the Router (DELL laptop Inspiron N1501, Android Smartphone, IPhone4S, Macbook Pro, XBMC/Pivos and Canon Pixma printer). All are connected wirelessly except the PIVOS which is through Ethernet.
Also connected to the router is my external USB hard drive (2TB).
The ASUS router I just bought a couple of weeks ago and have set it up myself.

**Problem/Issue** All devices that are connected to the router are working fine through the wireless connection - except the DELL laptop (which I used to set up and monitor the router). When I connect to the router through Ethernet cable I get excellent speeds of 50Mbps (higher than the rated promised speed of 30Mbps). However when connected through wireless it barely crawls and I get 2 Mbps max..measured using speedtest.net. I am using DELL laptop (INSPIRON N1501 Intel i3 with Windows 8 64bit 250GB 4MB RAM)

This problem has started only since the new router/modem combination was installed last week. Prior this I was using the a different router/modem (SMC Gateway with DLink DIR657) and it was fine. Switched as cable service provider now providign free modem and I was advised to get the ASUS router for its good performance.

Given that the issue is only with this laptop and only when using the wireless connection I suspect the problem lies there and most likely in the wireless network adapter. However being a novice in networking I don't know how to troubleshoot this. I am providing the following information if some one can help or provide some pointers of what to do.

**Laptop & Network Adapter details**
My laptop (INSPIRON N1501 Intel i3 with Windows8 250GB 4MBRAM) has a Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter. 
Driver installed is provided by Microsoft. version # 5.100.245.20 dated March 13. 2012.
I have checked that the driver for the Network adapter is the latest version using the Windows utility
Status Message under Broadcom Network Adapter properties is as below:
Driver Management has concluded the process to add Service BCM43XX for Device Instance ID PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4727&SUBSYS_00101028&REV_01\4&E81 4A4C&0&00E1 with the following status: 0.
Hardware ID 
PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4727&SUBSYS_00101028&REV_01

Just to add: there is 1 additional network adapter - not sure what they are for!

Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter

---

Windows IP Configuration

Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : VineetsPC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C0-CB-38-79-58-CE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C2-CB-38-79-58-CE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C0-CB-38-79-58-CE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.25(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 5, 2013 8:15:46 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, October 6, 2013 9:01:11 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

---

i also this link but dont find any such setting on my ASUS router remote command so not sure how to do this. Any ideas as this might be the issue?

### http://brikis98.blogspot.ca/2012/02/got-slow-download-but-fast-upload.html?m=1

Thank you in advance for your input and advice. If the above information is inadequate and more details are required please let me know how to get them (as I am networking novice!)

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the same wifi channel as your old modem? Your new router might be using a busy channel by default with lots of interference. You can check with [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/).

Try a different wifi encryption method on your router, or turn it off briefly to test.
See if you get much difference between WPA2 and WPA (don't bother with WEP). If you turn off encryption, you should see a roughly 20% improvement in speed, but beware that anyone can see your data.

Check your event logs and make sure your wifi card and driver is happy.

Beyond that, you can try installing [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and looking at the traffic for some clues (however it's not particularly friendly towards the network novice).

Comment: Wireshark - downloaded it and find it too complex...not sure what to look for in in.

Comment: At the outset let me thank you for your response and solution. Here is an update - Wireshark - downloaded it and find it too complex...not sure what to look for in in. Already had inSSIDer - no issues with channel.Checked event log - no wifi card and driver warnings/errors. However the switch to the WPA (TKIP) worked!.. Getting 5.5Mbps DL and 3Mbps UL. Much faster than before. Not in line with Ethernet speeds of 30MbpsDL - but better than 1.5Mbps. Any ideas how I can increase this further - other than buying a new laptop? Is it easy changing the network card on a laptop to get a better speed.